# Facebook Web Login "Sorry, something went wrong."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

For some reason my previously working Facebook Login stopped working. When I connect to Facebook through the code below, I get a popup window containing the following message:

> Sorry, something went wrong.
>   We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.
>
> Go Back

In the console it said something about https, so I configured my localhost development server to use https.

After doing this, I still get the same popup message, but without the https warning in the console.

I'm thinking maybe some of my settings aren't configured properly, so I'll add a screenshot of those below.

Here's my JS code for connecting to Facebook.

```
/**
 * Add files retrieved with getScript to cache.
 */
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });

/**
 * Get Facebook Graph SDK.
 */
$.getScript('https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'XXX',
        version: 'v3.2'
    });
});

/**
 * Social Connect with Custom Facebook Button.
 */
$('#facebook-connect-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    FB.login( function(fbResponse) {

        console.log(fbReponse);

        if ( fbResponse.status === 'connected' ) {

            //... Do stuff

        }

    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email', return_scopes: true });

});
```

And here are my Facebook Login settings in the developer section:

[image]

Comment: `auth_type: 'https'` - what’s this …? There is no auth type `https`, passing this bogus value is likely what is causing the dialog to error.

Comment: (You don’t need to specify any Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, that is for the server-side login flow.)

Comment: @misorude I think that's a leftover from a previous version.

Comment: Updated question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magically resolved itself after giving it half a day.

Comment: How can you do that, bro?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on web login.
**JavaScript SDK must be enabled for Facebook Login.**
You are using the JavaScript SDK to log in by setting the Login with JavaScript SDK key to "yes" and enter the domain of your page hosting the SDK in the Allowed Domains list for the JavaScript SDK

Step 1 must be completed correctly in this link
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web